# How can I parse multiple (unknown) date formats in python?

Tags: python, parsing, date

I have a bunch of excel documents I am extracting dates from. I am trying to convert these to a standard format so I can put them in a database. Is there a function I can throw these strings at and get a standard format back? Here is a small sample of my data:

The good thing is I know it is always Month/Day

```
10/02/09
07/22/09
09-08-2008
9/9/2008
11/4/2010
 03-07-2009
09/01/2010
```

I'd like to get them all into MM/DD/YYYY format. Is there a way I can do this without trying each pattern against the string?

Comment: Are dates always above 2000, and if not, where should the split between then 1900s and 2000s be?

Comment: Yes, dates are always post 2000

Answer (score 16, accepted):

```
import re

ss = '''10/02/09
07/22/09
09-08-2008
9/9/2008
11/4/2010
03-07-2009
09/01/2010'''


regx = re.compile('[-/]')
for xd in ss.splitlines():
    m,d,y = regx.split(xd)
    print xd,'   ','/'.join((m.zfill(2),d.zfill(2),'20'+y.zfill(2) if len(y)==2 else y))
```

result

```
10/02/09     10/02/2009
07/22/09     07/22/2009
09-08-2008     09/08/2008
9/9/2008     09/09/2008
11/4/2010     11/04/2010
03-07-2009     03/07/2009
09/01/2010     09/01/2010
```

### Edit 1

And **Edit 2** : taking account of the information on `'{0:0>2}'.format(day)` from JBernardo, I added a 4th solution, that appears to be the fastest

```
import re
from time import clock
iterat = 100

from datetime import datetime
dates = ['10/02/09', '07/22/09', '09-08-2008', '9/9/2008', '11/4/2010',
         ' 03-07-2009', '09/01/2010']

reobj = re.compile(
r"""\s*  # optional whitespace
(\d+)    # Month
[-/]     # separator
(\d+)    # Day
[-/]     # separator
(?:20)?  # century (optional)
(\d+)    # years (YY)
\s*      # optional whitespace""",
re.VERBOSE)

te = clock()
for i in xrange(iterat):
    ndates = (reobj.sub(r"\1/\2/20\3", date) for date in dates)
    fdates1 = [datetime.strftime(datetime.strptime(date,"%m/%d/%Y"), "%m/%d/%Y")
               for date in ndates]
print "Tim's method   ",clock()-te,'seconds'



regx = re.compile('[-/]')


te = clock()
for i in xrange(iterat):
    ndates = (reobj.match(date).groups() for date in dates)
    fdates2 = ['%s/%s/20%s' % tuple(x.zfill(2) for x in tu) for tu in ndates]
print "mixing solution",clock()-te,'seconds'


te = clock()
for i in xrange(iterat):
    ndates = (regx.split(date.strip()) for date in dates)
    fdates3 = ['/'.join((m.zfill(2),d.zfill(2),('20'+y.zfill(2) if len(y)==2 else y)))
              for m,d,y in ndates]
print "eyquem's method",clock()-te,'seconds'



te = clock()
for i in xrange(iterat):
    fdates4 = ['{:0>2}/{:0>2}/20{}'.format(*reobj.match(date).groups()) for date in dates]
print "Tim + format   ",clock()-te,'seconds'


print fdates1==fdates2==fdates3==fdates4
```

result

```
number of iteration's turns : 100
Tim's method    0.295053700959 seconds
mixing solution 0.0459111423379 seconds
eyquem's method 0.0192239516475 seconds
Tim + format    0.0153756971906 seconds 
True
```

The mixing solution is interesting because it combines the speed of my solution and the ability of the regex of Tim Pietzcker to **detect** dates in a string.

That's still more true for the solution combining Tim's one and the formating with `{:0>2}`. I cant' combine `{:0>2}` with mine because `regx.split(date.strip())` produces year with 2 OR 4 digits

Comment: I had already used my upvote on your first answer, but I would +1 it again for the performance improvements and testing.

Answer (score 26):

The third-party module [dateutil](https://dateutil.readthedocs.io/en/stable) has a function `parse` that operates similarly to PHP's `strtotime`: you don't need to specify a particular date format, it just tries a bunch of its own.

```
>>> from dateutil.parser import parse
>>> parse("10/02/09", fuzzy=True)
datetime.datetime(2009, 10, 2, 0, 0)  # default to be in American date format
```

It also allows you to specify different assumptions:

> - **dayfirst** – Whether to interpret the first value in an ambiguous 3-integer date (e.g. 01/05/09) as the day (True) or month (False). If yearfirst is set to True, this distinguishes between YDM and YMD. If set to None, this value is retrieved from the current parserinfo object (which itself defaults to False).
> - **yearfirst** – Whether to interpret the first value in an ambiguous 3-integer date (e.g. 01/05/09) as the year. If True, the first number is taken to be the year, otherwise the last number is taken to be the year. If this is set to None, the value is retrieved from the current parserinfo object (which itself defaults to False).

Comment: Does the function **parse** of **dateutil** detect dates in a string , or does it need to receive a date as argument ?

Comment: parse('2023年12月4日10点',fuzzy=True)
datetime.datetime(2010, 12, 4, 0, 0)  got wrong result

Answer (score 10):

If you don't want to install a third-party module like dateutil:

```
import re
from datetime import datetime
dates = ['10/02/09', '07/22/09', '09-08-2008', '9/9/2008', '11/4/2010', ' 03-07-2009', '09/01/2010']
reobj = re.compile(
    r"""\s*  # optional whitespace
    (\d+)    # Month
    [-/]     # separator
    (\d+)    # Day
    [-/]     # separator
    (?:20)?  # century (optional)
    (\d+)    # years (YY)
    \s*      # optional whitespace""", 
    re.VERBOSE)
ndates = [reobj.sub(r"\1/\2/20\3", date) for date in dates]
fdates = [datetime.strftime(datetime.strptime(date,"%m/%d/%Y"), "%m/%d/%Y")
          for date in ndates]
```

Result:

```
['10/02/2009', '07/22/2009', '09/08/2008', '09/09/2008', '11/04/2010', '03/07/2009', '09/01/2010']
```

Comment: hello mister @Tim Pietzcker - **strptime** is a very slow function. See the edit of my answer - Using date for an other object than the class datetime.date isn't very good because it overrides datetime.date. It's not the case in your code but it is risky for the code in which your snippet will be included. - And it's better to make **ndates** to be a generator

Comment: @Tim Pietzcker The **Tim's + format** solution is shorter, clearer and faster than your pure **Tim's solution** (see the edit in my answer), then.... your solution, though overupvoted, isn't the best, sorry.

Answer (score 4):

You can use a regex like `r'(\d+)\D(\d+)\D(\d+)'` to get the month, day and year in a tuple with the `re.findall` function.

then just concatenate the 2-digit years with the number `20` or `19` and use the separator you want to join then back:

`'/'.join(the_list)`

As pointed by Tim:

To normalize days, just do `'{0:0>2}'.format(day)` and the same to months.