# Elegant way of parsing dates in python

Tags: python

I'm looking to parse date from a string. This string can hold different formats, which I don't know in advance.

```
from datetime import datetime

try:
    return datetime.strptime(text, '%m/%d/%Y'))
except:
    try:
        return datetime.strptime(text, '%m/%d/%y')) 
    except:
        try:
            return datetime.strptime(text, '%Y/%m/%d'))
        except:
            try:
                return datetime.strptime(text, '%b%d/%Y'))
            except:
                return None
```

Obviously, this looks too verbose. I'm sure there's a better way using map, but I'd really like to hear your opinions - I hate reinventing the wheel.

Comment: You could at least use a loop.

Comment: Check that http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7048828/how-can-i-parse-multiple-unknown-date-formats-in-python

Comment: For some reason, I wouldn't like to use dateutils.parse. Let's say I have a small set of formats as described. Looping is definitely better.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

```
from datetime import datetime

def getdate(text):
    formats = ('%m/%d/%Y', '%m/%d/%y', '%Y/%m/%d', '%b%d/%Y')
    for format in formats:
        try:
            return datetime.strptime(text, format)
        except:
            pass
```

Answer (score 4):

How about looping through provided formats priorities?

```
from datetime import datetime

def convert(text):
    for format in [ '%m/%d/%Y', '%m/%d/%y', '%Y/%m/%d', '%b%d/%Y' ]:
        try:
            return datetime.strptime(text, format)
        except:
            continue
    return None
```

Comment: Fix the `SyntaxError` on the return statement, specify the exception in the `except` (which is swallowing the above SyntaxError) and that `continue` can just be a `pass` :)

Comment: Will `.strptime()` ever raise anything besides a `ValueError`?

Comment: It can also rise `TypeError` if we call it with `strptime( None, '%m/%d' )` and I guess in some rare cases also memory exceptions

Answer (score 3):

Just use [`datetutil.parser.parse`](http://labix.org/python-dateutil#head-c0e81a473b647dfa787dc11e8c69557ec2c3ecd2) as [described in answers to this question](https://stackoverflow.com/q/9516025/180174)