# Equating python datetimes

Tags: python, datetime, strptime

I am working with a few slightly different styles of python datetimes. Problem is, I'd like to be able to equate them and I can't. From the database, I am getting datetimes in the format of:

```
datetime.date(2010, 11, 15)
```

Which, when returned, outputs:

```
2010-11-15
```

However, on my end, I need to turn some dates in a csv file into a date time. I do so by using the `datetime.datetime.strptime` package. So, here my code looks like this:

```
date = '11/15/2010' #The format in the CSV file
date = date.replace('/', ' ')
date2 = datetime.datetime.strptime(date, '%m %d %Y')
```

However, date2, when printed, outputs:

```
2010-11-15 00:00:00
```

And the two dates, though actually equivalent, won't evaluate to `True` when I throw a `==` in between them. Is there a way to use `datetime.datetime.strptime` to leave out hours, minutes, seconds? I'd like to conform to the format used in the first example (my database). Thanks

Comment: This question may help: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7048828/how-can-i-parse-multiple-unknown-date-formats-in-python

Comment: Aside: Why `str.replace()`? Why not `datetime.strptime('%m/%d/%Y')`?

Comment: I like it, I only did that since the python docs had them separated by space, never really put any thought into it

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You're trying to compare a `datetime` and a `date`. To compare them, simply do:

```
date2.date() == datetime.date(2010,11,15)
```

and you should be fine.

A bit more context:

```
In [1]: import datetime

In [2]: datetime.date.today()
Out[2]: datetime.date(2013, 10, 28)

In [3]: datetime.datetime.now()
Out[3]: datetime.datetime(2013, 10, 28, 11, 5, 43, 997651)

In [4]: datetime.datetime.now() == datetime.date.today()
Out[4]: False

In [5]: datetime.datetime.now().date() == datetime.date.today()
Out[5]: True
```