# Python filtering and selecting from list

Tags: python, list, filtering

I need to make a python function that opens a file, reads in the text and then outputs on the Python GUI any entries that contain dates. Examples for valid dates include "1/30/10", "1/30/2010", "1-30-2010", "01-30-2010", "30.1.2010", "30. 1. 2010", and "2010-01-30." It should have few false positives such as "13010", "01302010", or "30-30-10" as dates.

What I have so far is this

```
import sys

def main():
    infile = open('testdate.txt', 'r')

    for line in infile:
        words = line.split()
        for date in words:
            if ____ in date:
                print date


    infile.close()

main()
```

I know that the `line.split()` function is able to separate all entries in the text file. What I'm unsure about is how to loop through this new list and ONLY take in dates. How would I go about filtering only dates out?

Comment: Have a look at [datetime.strptime](http://docs.python.org/2/library/datetime.html#datetime.datetime.strptime). List all possible date formats(in the file) and try to parse; if parsing is successful, print.

Comment: How would I go about using datetime.strptime(date_string, format)? I'm guessing I will need to import datetime, then what exactly is date_string? Is this the variable I'm looking at when I loop through the items in "words"? And for format, how do I go about using said formats?

Comment: Here's a question with some good answers on parsing dates in multiple formats, using both home-brewed and third-party parsers.  Aside from that, it looks like you're on the right track.  http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7048828/how-can-i-parse-multiple-unknown-date-formats-in-python

Answer (score 0):

Find out all possible formats and try to parse those. This may help:

```
>>> from datetime import datetime
>>> possible_fmts = ["%m/%d/%y","%m/%d/%Y","%m-%d-%y","%m-%d-%Y","%d.%m.%Y","%d. %m. %Y","%Y-%m-%d"]
>>> test_text = "1/30/10,1/30/2010,1-30-2010,01-30-2010,30.1.2010,30. 1. 2010,2010-01-30"
>>> for date_token in test_text.split(','):
        for fmt in possible_fmts:
            try:
                print datetime.strptime(date_token, fmt)
                break
            except ValueError, e:
                pass


2010-01-30 00:00:00
2010-01-30 00:00:00
2010-01-30 00:00:00
2010-01-30 00:00:00
2010-01-30 00:00:00
2010-01-30 00:00:00
2010-01-30 00:00:00
```