# Find dates with Regex

Tags: python, regex

I am trying to write code that clean up dates in different date formats (such as `3/14/2015`, `03-14-2015`, and `2015/3/14`) by replacing them with dates in a single, standard format. So far I have wrote my regex expression but it's not working the way I would like.

```
import pyperclip,re

dateRegex = re.compile(r'''
    (\d|\d{2}|\d{4})  # match 1 digit, or two digits, or four digits
    (\s|-|\.|\/) # match either a space or a dash or a period or a backslash
    (\d{2}|\d) # match either 2 digits or one
    (\s|-|\.\/) # match either a space or a dash or a period or a backslash
    (\d{4}|\d{2}) # match either 4 or 2 digits.
    ''',)

text = "12/25/0000, 10.21.1955, 10-21-1985 6-5-1995 2004/2/21 5/25/2111 4999.2.21 "
a = dateRegex.findall(text):
```

Any idea why this isn't working?

Comment: Have you considered just using e.g. [`python-dateutil`](https://dateutil.readthedocs.io/en/stable/)? Also it's *"digits"*, FYI.

Comment: Related: http://stackoverflow.com/q/7048828/189134

Comment: you have random syntax things wrong with this code, such as a trailing comma after your pattern and a colon after the `findall`. I hope these are all just mistakes made when copying the code. Likewise, I hope those comments for each line are just for SO demonstrative purposes and not actually in your code because those wouldn't be parsed as comments but rather part of the pattern.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This code works [(see live)](http://ideone.com/ly6fvs):

```
import re
p = re.compile(ur'''(\d|\d{2}|\d{4})  # match 1 didget, or two didgets, or four didgets
                    ([-\s./]) # match either a space or a dash or a period or a backslash
                    (\d{1,2}) # match either 2 digets or one
                    ([-\s./]) # match either a space or a dash or a period or a backslash
                    (\d{4}|\d{2}) # match either 4 or 2 didgets.''', re.VERBOSE)
test_str = u"12/25/0000, 10.21.1955, 10-21-1985 6-5-1995 2004/2/21 5/25/2111 4999.2.21 "

print(p.findall(test_str))
```

You forget the option `re.VERBOSE` which means:

> Spaces and text after a `#` in the pattern are ignored

Comment: Awesome. Thanks for the help

Comment: Any idea why it's only printing dates with a "-" and not printing the other formatted dates?

Comment: `\d|\d{2}|\d{4}` => `\d(?:\d(?:\d{2})?)?` and `\d{4}|\d{2}` => `\d{2}(?:\d{2})?`. Isn't it better like this?

Comment: @CasimiretHippolyte it indeed works too but I find it harder to read